# How to check whether particular html element is already present or not before inserting using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to Jquery, please help me.
At present I am inserting asterisk class in the header , but I want to check one more condition, before inserting , Please help me how do I check that.
At present its keep on inserting every Edit button click in the Grid. But I want to insert only once , If it is already present on the header then I should not insert again
mycode, I am using Kendo Edit Grid-
[image: My Present Result from the below code]

```
edit: function (e) {
    var grid = this; e.container.find('td').each(function (_, x) 
       { 
         var cell = $(x);
         var input = cell.find('input[name]'); 
         if (input.attr('name')) { 
            var headerCell = grid.thead.find('th:eq(' + cell.index() + ')');
            headerCell.append($('')); 
         } 
      });
}
```

CSS class name -

```
.asterisk:after {
    content: " *";
    color: #b1001d;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code that you have tried and getting error

Comment: its not clear from the code what you want to achieve. please edit your question and explain a bit more.

Comment: I am not getting error , instead it will place the  asterisk , howmany times we press Edit button , so I need to put only one asterisk if the user click on Edit button. Please refer the image which I have posted in my question

Comment: @GaganDeep `input = $(x).find()`, which is a `jQuery` element

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava - here x is parameter in the function

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the vanilla javascript code. because jquery isn't usefull anymore.

```
 if(typeof(element)!== 'undefined'){
//your code
//eg:
const newElement = '<h1>hello</h1>'
element.append(newElement)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response

Comment: Was this the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this using below code :

```
 $('.asterisk').remove();
```